# HQL and checking if object is null or object field have specific value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I have problem with executing following query:

```
from Customer c where c.connectedUserID = 1 and (c.connectedFinancialAnalyst is null or c.connectedFinancialAnalyst.completed = false)
```

object c.connectedFinancialAnalyst can be null. What I need is to find Customers that dont have financial analyst or property in financial analyst has specific value.

Edit:
completed property is boolean in postgres and in java

Output generated by Hibernate

```
select
        customer0_.id as id1_0_,
        customer0_.birthDate as birthDat2_0_,
        customer0_.birthPlace as birthPla3_0_,
        customer0_.city as city4_0_,
        customer0_.email as email5_0_,
        customer0_.fatherName as fatherNa6_0_,
        customer0_.motherName as motherNa7_0_,
        customer0_.name as name8_0_,
        customer0_.pesel as pesel9_0_,
        customer0_.phoneNumber as phoneNu10_0_,
        customer0_.postalCode as postalC11_0_,
        customer0_.secondName as secondN12_0_,
        customer0_.sex as sex13_0_,
        customer0_.street as street14_0_,
        customer0_.surname as surname15_0_,
        customer0_.connectedFinancialAnalyst_id as connect17_0_,
        customer0_.connectedUserID as connect16_0_ 
    from
        Customer customer0_ cross 
    join
        FinancialAnalyst financiala1_ 
    where
        customer0_.connectedFinancialAnalyst_id=financiala1_.id 
        and customer0_.connectedUserID=1 
        and (
            customer0_.connectedFinancialAnalyst_id is null 
            or financiala1_.completed='false'
        )
```

Comment: Column `Completed` is it VARCHAR or BIT ??

Comment: PostGresql says it is boolean.

Comment: then it should be `'false'`. i.e enclosed inside single quotes `'`.  Check out this [`link`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-boolean.html) here.

Comment: i have already tried this. I thinh that the problem comes up when I try to check value on unexisting object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be explicit that you want to do a left join

```
from Customer c 
left join c.connectedFinancialAnalyst as analyst
where c.connectedUserID = 1 and (analyst.completed is null or analyst.completed = false)
```

Comment: Let me know which one works for you and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've tried this, but it have the same output as ealier. im quite sure that problem is with: 'c.connectedFinancialAnalyst.completed is null or c.connectedFinancialAnalyst.completed = false'

Comment: Try doing a left join.

Comment: It returned expected number of rows, now i have to deal with returned object's becouse they r objects of other type

Comment: If you have select c from Customer c, then you will get the Customer object.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: It returns me "Object" not Customer, Now i try to find out why ^^

Comment: Should be able to cast it to Customer.

Comment: I come up with exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.crm.User.Customer, I thought that jsf might have problem with casting but when i tried to do this manualy i had already same problem :( 

It seems to be the problem with join. Maybe i have wrong annotations? But in the other hand, if it would be the problem with annotations i won't be able to connect this two object's

Comment: I think that I should rewrite this part of code to Criteria query. Maybe it would work.

Comment: Hopefully I helped you go down the right path.  If so, I would appreciate you accepting my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm, i've tried with easier version:
from Customer c where c.connectedUserID = 1 and (c.connectedFinancialAnalyst.completed != 'true') but it seems to not work too :(

Answer (score 0):

I rewritten my code to Criteria and evrything works great. I suppose tkat the problem was with left join. When I used criteria i had to append Left Outter join like:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Customer.class, "c").createAlias("c.connectedFinancialAnalyst", "analyst", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

Maybe when i would change left join at query to left outter join everything might work great ^^. But now my code seems to be a little bit more user friendly ^^